Series expansion not working with $\sqrt{1-x^d}$
Why can't Mathematica expand simple functions like $$\sqrt{1-x^d}$$ in series? When I give particular values of $d$, then it simplifies but not otherwise. For now, I want $d \in \mathbb{N}$, and want to see the 1st few, say $3$ terms. I even tried to simplify the argument by assuming $d>0$ i.e. I ran the code:
Series[FullSimplify[Sqrt[(1 - x^d)], 
  Assumptions -> {d \[Element] PositiveIntegers, d > 0}], {x, 0, 3}]

and nothing happened: Mathematica returned the input. How to make mathematica do this?

(1) I get the first argument only, not the complete input. That's probably what you meant, but I thought I would make sure. (2) Block[{d = Sqrt[3]}, Series[Sqrt[(1 - x^d)], {x, 0, 3}]] returns the square root, not a series. So it does not work for some values for d; therefore I wouldn't expect it to work for a general d.

(1) Yes, I am getting $\sqrt{1-x^d}$ as output. (2) I am looking for natural integers only, for which putting any value of $d$ explicitly, does work.

Series does not handle nonrational exponents.

Perhaps this?:
Asymptotic[Sqrt[(1 - u)], {u, 0, 2}] /. u -> x^d
(*  1 - x^d/2 - x^(2 d)/8  *)

If we examine the output of Series, we can see a limitation in the data structure used to represent series. This makes series with parameters that affect which powers appear impossible to represent. For instance,
Series[Sqrt[(1 - x^4)], {x, 0, 10}, 
  Assumptions -> {d \[Element] Reals, d > 0, x > 0}] // InputForm
(*  SeriesData[x, 0, {1, 0, 0, 0, -1/2, 0, 0, 0, -1/8}, 0, 11, 1]  *)

We see explicit coefficients (zero) for the missing powers. There are d-1 of them. For an indeterminate d, such an explicit list is impossible.

It is good to know the workaround, but I argue that this is something Asymptotic should do out of the box. I agree with you that it is not the job of Series.

@yarchik On the one hand, I agree but you should tell WRI; on the other, Asymptotic[Sqrt[(1 - x^d)], {x, 0, 10}] should have 1 + Floor[10/d] nonzero terms, which is indeterminate. Sum[Derivative[k][Sqrt[1 - #^d] &][0] x^k/k!, {k, 0, 10}] fails rather spectacularly.

Since the expansion is at an analytic point of the function, the power series is a Taylor expansion:
$$
S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{d^n}{dx}(1-x^d)^{1/2}}{n!}x^n
$$
However when $d$ is indeterminate, there arises indeterminate terms of the form $0^0$ which Mathematica cannot directly evaluate.  Consider the first two derivatives of the expansion for indeterminate $d$:
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx}(1-x^d)^{1/2}=-\frac{d^2 x^{2 d-2}}{4 \left(1-x^d\right)^{3/2}}-\frac{(d-1) d x^{d-2}}{2 \sqrt{1-x^d}}
$$
and note there is a term $x^{d-2}$ that would have to be evaluated at $x=0$ and $d=2$ producing $0^0$.  We could avoid this by evaluating the limits separately with the following but inefficient code:
myExpansion[d_, n_] := 
  Module[{p, q, 
    s}, (Limit[
       Sum[(D[(1 - x^p)^(1/2), {x, v}])/(v!) s^v, {v, 0, n}, 
        Assumptions -> Element[PositiveIntegers, p]], p -> d] /. 
      x -> 0) /. s -> x
   ];
myExpansion[2, 6] 

which produces after several seconds:
$$
1-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{8}-\frac{x^6}{16}
$$

Shouldn't the coefficients agree with Series[Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, 0, 6}], or are you doing something different than I thought you were?

@Michael E2:  Ok, sorry, I copied it down wrong.  Corrected.  Don't know why the limits take so long to evaluate for more than a few terms.  Maybe there's a faster way.

In that case, why not use Series[Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, 0, 6}] or Asymptotic instead of myExpansion?

Sanjana wanted an indeterminate expression $(1-x^d)^{1/2}$ to use which Series will not evaluate.  I just thought it was  interesting why Series couldn't do so and hypothesized it was because of the indeterminate form $0^0$  in the general expression with $d$ and a challenge to try and figure out how to resolve it with code.

Okay, thanks. I think I see what you were doing. Like Series, myExpansion works only for specific d and n. I thought perhaps myExpansion[d, 6] was supposed to work, and I was missing something.

Actually myExpansion[d,6]  generates the first six terms  of Taylor series in $d$ except it contains forms like $0^{-2+d},0^{-3+d},\cdots ,0^{-6+d}$, one of which is indeterminate.  For example myExpansion[d,2] gives: $$\frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{0^{2 d-2} d^2}{4 \left(1-0^d\right)^{3/2}}-\frac{0^{d-2} (d-1) d}{2 \sqrt{1-0^d}}\right) x^2-\frac{0^{d-1} d x}{2 \sqrt{1-0^d}}+\sqrt{1-0^d}$$

Right, and is $0^d$ etc. useful in Mma? I assumed you thought it wasn't, which is why I said it "doesn't work." For instance myExpansion[d, 6] /. d -> 2 doesn't agree with myExpansion[2, 6].

Ok, I see what you mean.  The expression I gave above, when $d\to 2$ is $1$ which is not the expected  $1-x^2/2$ for $n=2$.
